# Updating xml using stylesheet with special characters

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am updating an xml document using special tag characters. I use a style sheet to add nodes. The value of the node is build in the java code and passed as a String using xsl:param..

The issue is I am adding node which has java string value:

<nodeName>value1</nodeName>

and it appears as

`&lt`;nodeName`&gt`;value1`&lt`;/nodeName`&gt`;

in the xml document

Please advise how can i amend the style sheet or the escape the java string value.

Regards,
B

Comment: Please add your xslt code.

Comment: This looks like you're adding a String (as you say - java string value) but that is not how it works. The string then will be escaped if it contains < > etc., that's what you see. You have to add a node/an element instead of a string.

Comment: Don't build XML as a string, use an API or language dedicated to XML generation. As you already use XSLT, you have a tool to generate XML so if the use case is as simple as shown then use e.g. `<xsl:param name="p1" select="'value1'"/>` and then inside of your XSLT you can simply generate a result element `<nodeName><xsl:value-of select="$p1"/></nodeName>`. If you really think you need to build XML in your Java code to pass it to your XSLT processor then you need to create a tree structure like a DOM tree, in any case it then depends on the used XSLT processor which data structure you can use.

Comment: As a quick fix, if you have a string, inside of XSLT all you can do is use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$my-param" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` to avoid the escaping of markup. But the whole approach seems inappropriate, XSLT is the right tool to create XML.

Comment: Thanks the disable-output-escaping option works. I have it working with DomFactory too, where I add the Node at the appropriate place. Is xsl:param only used for Strings? I tried using a Node xsl:param but that did not work. The Node has nested elements.